# How to switch images on click with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using visual studios and I want to make a sprite look like it's walking. So when I press the left arrow key the sprite moves left but I want to change the image each time I press the key so his other leg is forward and it seems like he is walking. At first, I had a gif but it doesn't have the same effect.

I'm using visual studios and only new but can't seem to find an updated answer. If there is anyways to improve my question please let me know. Thank you!

I'm Using Windows Form App (.NET Framework)

Comment: You use Visual Studio to write programs in general. You need to pick a framework/library (like say Unity or WPF or whatever). To improve your question, tell us what libraries you are using, and then post your code saying "here's my code, here's my goal, here's the problem(s) I'm encountering, how do I fix it. Your question should include a [mcve]

Comment: What kind of application is this?  WinForms, WPF, something else?  It makes a huge difference!

Comment: application is winforms app

Comment: Load up the different sprite images into an [ImageList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist?view=netcore-3.1) and then change the image being displayed upon each keypress...

Comment: what is the code to change the image

Answer (score 1):

> what is the code to change the image

If you want to traverse through the pictures in the ImageList, you can define an field `index` to store the index of images.

Please refer to the following code.

```
int index = 0;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        if (index > imageList1.Images.Count - 1)
            index = 0;
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[index++];
    }
}
```

The test result,

[image]